# Change Background Color for Entire Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, background-color

Is there a way to change the Background color into `xlNone`, 
for example to the entire sheet. I see that you can put a background image...
But how can you change the color for all cells in the sheet?

Comment: Recording the action as a macro then looking @ the source should tell you this no?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this quite easy with this code:

```
Public Sub Demo()
  'set color
  WorksheetName.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 'black
  'clear color
  WorksheetName.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
end sub
```

Or if you don't need VBA, just click at this little icon in the corner:

[image]

and select a color, or to use no color - using right click menu or ribbon menu.

Just because of the other answers, I want to remind - it is not necessary to use selections! This is bad macro-recorder style. There are only few occations, where using selections is necessary or a good idea. You can always just use a specific range.

Comment: Yes, I think your solution is complete and faster!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select    
Cells.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can change the background color for all cells in the current sheet

```
 Cells.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505   'grey color
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: You're setting the background color to a greyish color, not removing it ;)

Comment: @t.thielemans, that is what the person who asked the question wants, isn't it?

Comment: @Ahmad You have to remove whatever color might be there first. But even if I did that, I couldn't get this to work if I did: `.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505` off of a Range of cells.