# EPPlus Set background color of entire worksheet

Tags: c#, epplus

Using **EPPlus**, I understand that you can set the background color of individual cells, or a range of cells as follows:

```
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);
```

Is there any way to set the background color of the entire worksheet? Or is this just a case of setting a very wide range of cells?

So for example I could do:

```
ws.Cells["A1:AZ10000"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells["A1:AZ10000"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);
```

I'm not sure if there is a performance concern doing this? I tried it with "A1:ZZ100000", it just hung.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008714/change-background-color-for-entire-sheet help?

Comment: @mjwills - its epplus not excel

Comment: I've updated the question to include EPPlus in the question as well.

Comment: @Jacques - ExcelRange  is not working .....?

Comment: Yes I know @PranayRana . But does EPPlus have an equivalent method?

Comment: @Jacques - i know that i used EPPlus in my code ...

Comment: @mjwills regardless of whether or not EPPlus has similar functions there may be other implications to consider

Comment: Such as @Jacques ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use cells directly without specifying address range:

```
ws.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);
```

Tested it, it takes no time.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler yet!

```
    ws.SetBackgroundColor(Color.HotPink);
```